# Traverse thru array elements and extract delimited values when condition is satisfied

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop thru an array and extract its delimited values that match every date in a range. For e.g., in the picture below:

1. I have a date range, say 01-01 to 01-10.
2. I also have a list of strings (see second pic).
3. In the array below (see first pic), I have three different values delimited by a semi-colon.
4. For all matching strings (from second pic) e.g., SISBTXTRPR-(number) and date, I want to extract the last part of the array value.

***Picture 1***
[image: Picture 1]

***Picture 2***

[image: Picture 2]

So, for all array values that match "SISBTXTRPR-4649" (the string from picture 2) and a date  (in this case 12-12), I want to extract "2h" from the array. The date range for each string, in this case, "SISBTXTRPR-4649" will be 10 days. I am racking my brain on how to do this :(

This is all I could come up with so far:

```
While i < UBound(sTimeStamp)
If StrComp(Trim(Format(Now(), "MM-DD")), Trim(Split(sTimeStamp(9), ";")(1))) = 0 And StrComp(Trim(Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AN" & iCounter)), Trim(Split(sTimeStamp(1), ";")(0))) Then

End If
i = i + 1
Wend
```

Link to file

[Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hejs1fc6t7a9ai/Book1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand at all what you are trying to do. When you say "f**or all array values** that match "SISBTXTRPR-4649", what do you mean? Do you have more then such a string in that array? In your picture I do not see two such identical strings. Besides that, how do you intend to return that extracted "2h"? Do you intend to extract only that "2D"? And based on what do you state that "The date range for each string, in this case, "SISBTXTRPR-4649" will be 10 days"?

Comment: @FaneDuru - No worries, let me rephrase it. So, what I want is, I want to first read the items in pic  2 (originally stored in a spreadsheet range) one at a time. For e.g., SISBTXTRPR-4649 is first read and now, I want to go the array (pic 2) 'sTimeStamp' and compare that list for SISBTXTRPR-4649. So, I will have three matching items. For each of those matching items from the array (e.g., SISBTXTRPR-4649;12-12;2h, SISBTXTRPR-4649;12-13;2h, SISBTXTRPR-4649;12-16;2h), I have to compare again the date (the middle part 12-12, 12-13 and 12-16) against another array that has dates in MM-DD format.

Comment: This date range array will have values starting from 01-01 all the way thru 01-14. So, in this case, there will not be any match for SISBTXTRPR-4649 because the dates do not match (it only have values for 12-12, 12-13 and 12-16. Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Yes, it helps something, but I think it is not enough... I mean, in principle, I think I know what is to be done, but I am not so good in order to do it blind. So, I would propose you to bring here some relevant new pictures, or better to share your workbook on google drive. I mean, to offer relevant data, even dummy: An excel Range to be loaded in an array (but that array, if picture, to have at least 2 occurrences), the range to be iterated exists, the range with date in your right format and better explain what is to be done in case of occurrence for a specific condition happens...

Comment: At least a message box with the text "Exists!"...

Comment: Just an observation: Even if the date are expressed in format MM-DD (so, Excel displays them), they are long. When you load them in an array, you will not have there the displayed string... You must compare long to long. The way to transform 12-12 in date is not so complicated, but very important. The fact you did it correct would be testing it like Debug.Print CLng(MyDate) to return a long.  43841 for today. Even if the date is expressed in that format, Excel automatically add the current year...

Comment: I would just like to see that date range in format MM-DD...

Comment: @FaneDuru - I have attached a spreadsheet w/ values representing the Tasks (excel range), sTimeStamp array and Date range Array. And, yes, a message box saying "Exists" when the condition is satisfied will do. With regards to long format of the date, I am shortening current date with a built-in function  like this: format_date = Format(t, "MM-DD") where 't' is the current system date. The output will be 01-11 for example.

Comment: I do not mind sharing the base code but all these items - the tasks list (SISBTXTRPR-4649), date range array and sTimeStamp array are dynamically generated and you would have to connect to the JIRA server via SSO credentials that I am afraid will not work if you are outside of the company's network.

Comment: It remains unclear to me what you are doing. You show nothing to indicate what you are doing with the results. In your sample workbook, most, but not all, of the tasks have multiple matches in the timestamp data. You really need to clarify this question. As is, it does not seem particularly useful to me.

Comment: The bottom line is, I am trying to generate a task burn-down chart (using line graph). JIRA sucks with metric reports. Anyway, the task list is all of the tasks in a given iteration. I am extracting JIRA data via a REST call in JSON format and that is presented in the "sTimeStamp" array. This array has all the logged data on those tasks. I generate these three items (Task list, TimeStamp array and Dates) every single day. The ultimate goal is to ONLY extract hours for the matching date and task. Does it remotely answer your question?

Comment: @Jrules80 : OK. I will provide a kind of solution in some minutes. Initially able to work and we'l see how to make it shorter and more elegant in a further step. But, theoretically, it is possible to have more occurrences (in the Date range) for a specific Task in the TimeStamp ranges. Do you need to capture all those occurrences, or it is enough to simple skip the next occurrence if the first one appears?

Comment: The updated code (short variant included) can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuMQua3NV0cTq-JCHnGA0hhg75ube5VO/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next code will return occurrences for each string in 'Task' range matching the date from its corresponding 'sTimeStamp Array' string with the one from the 'Date Range Array'. Each occurrence will be add to the next column of 'Task' string column:

```
Private Sub findOccurrences()
  Dim sTask As Worksheet, sStamp As Worksheet, sDate As Worksheet
  Dim arrTask As Variant, arrStamp As Variant, arrDate As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrS As Variant, El As Variant, dtRef As Date

  Set sTask = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Task")
  Set sStamp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sTimeStamp Array")
  Set sDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Date Range Array")
    arrTask = sTask.Range("A2:A" & sTask.Range("A" & sTask.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    arrStamp = sStamp.Range("A2:A" & sStamp.Range("A" & sStamp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    arrDate = sDate.Range("A2:A" & sDate.Range("A" & sDate.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

    '____________________________________________________________________________  
    sTask.Range("B2:K" & sTask.Range("A" & sTask.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Clear  
    Do While i < UBound(arrStamp)
        i = i + 1
        arrS = Split(arrStamp(i, 1), ";")
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrTask)
            If arrS(0) = arrTask(j, 1) Then
                For Each El In arrDate
                    dtRef = DateValue(Format(El, "MM-DD"))
                    If dtRef = DateValue(Format(arrS(1), "MM-DD")) Then
                        Debug.Print arrS(0) & " (row number " & j + 1 & "), interval """ & _
                                                                        El & """ exists."
                        sTask.Cells(j + 1, sTask.Cells(j + 1, _
                            sTask.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = El
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next j
    Loop

End Sub
```

And the short variant working similar to your approach, finding the occurrences for Today date (if I correctly deduced what you intended to achieve), replace the looping part with this:

```
'______________________________________________________________________________
    sStamp.Range("B2:B" & sStamp.Range("A" & sStamp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Clear
sTask.Range("A2:A" & sTask.Range("A" & sStamp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
While i < UBound(arrStamp)
    i = i + 1
    If StrComp(DateValue(Format(Date, "MM-DD")), DateValue(Split(arrStamp(i, 1), ";")(1))) = 0 And _
                                Not isMatchErr(CStr(Split(arrStamp(i, 1), ";")(1)), arrDate) Then
        Debug.Print "OK for """ & Split(arrStamp(i, 1), ";")(0) & """ of row """ & i & """."
        sStamp.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = "OK"
        If Not isMatchErr(CStr(Split(arrStamp(i, 1), ";")(0)), arrTask) Then
            rowOK = WorksheetFunction.Match(Split(arrStamp(i, 1), ";")(0), arrTask, 0) + 1
            sTask.Range("A" & rowOK).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Wend
```

And add the next function:

```
Function isMatchErr(strTime As String, arrDate As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim k As Long
   On Error Resume Next
     k = WorksheetFunction.Match(strTime, arrDate, 0)
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: isMatchErr = True
     End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Besides the message in Immediate Window, an "OK" will be put on column B:B for all occurrences (in 'sTimeStamp Array' sheet) and background of the matching cell (in 'Task' sheet will be colored in red... In order to do that, I added a new record and modified an existing cell, for "Today" ("01-12"). Please do the same in order to obtain at least two results in column B:B.

Please confirm that this is what you wanted. If not, please better clarify the need...

Comment: Thank you! I am able to tweak my code based on your answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jrules80: Welcome! Here, people do not like sharing your workbook. Understandable, in a way... Everybody must see what is to be done, but without having your sample book, I am afraid I wouldn't able to exactly understand your need. That's why, I would recommend you to better focus on your future questions accuracy... :-)